# What's beneficial about hitting an enemy's head?

Tags: battle-brothers

I've noticed some weapons and attacks, like **Lash**, offer a chance to hit an enemies head. That's all fine and dandy, but I can't actually figure out what benefit there is to hitting an enemy in the head. I've tried poking around on the subreddit and wiki, but haven't head much luck  tracking down an answer.

[image: lash offers 100% chance to hit head]

**What's beneficial about hitting an enemy in the head?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Hits to the head are "critical hits" and deal 1.5x normal damage.  (Note that this isn't true of the automatic head damage from the [Split Man](https://battlebrothers.fandom.com/wiki/Split_Man_(15_fatigue)) skill, which has [its own mechanics](https://battlebrothers.fandom.com/wiki/Combat_Mechanics#Split_Man)).
- If you can reliably hit the head with most/all of your attacks, you can break through the target's head armor and kill them via health damage without having to batter through their body armor's durability.  This will kill them much more quickly than splitting hits between head and body, since it bypasses a large portion of the target's effective HP.
- Relatedly, if you kill a target without fully depleting their body armor's durability (via some combination of head shots and attacks that ignore high % of armor), then they are more likely to drop their body armor as loot (in general, enemy armor with fully depleted durability is destroyed and will not drop).